# text : background color same size

Tags: css, background, html

My web site http://maximearchambault.com

I will like to have the same color background size for my 3 section, commercial, personal project and info / contact. The blue need to be 180 pixels.

```
/* section title */
#index span.section_title,
#index span.section_title a {  color: #000000; font-weight: bold; background: #00FFFF; }
```

This is located in my style.css.

Answer (score 0):

Color has no size. If you want to enforce certain measures, use `width` (or `height`) respectively, i.e. `width: 180px;`

Answer (score 0):

on line 75 of your style css -

```
#index span.section_title, #index span.section_title a {

color: black;
font-weight: bold;
background: cyan;
width: 180px; //add this
display: block; ///add this
}
```

you may want to add it to the span only, in which case add a new rule -

```
#index span.section_title {
        width: 180px; //add this
        display: block; ///add this
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try this

```
#index ul.section {
  font-size: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  border: 1px solid #636363;
  background: cyan;
  width: 180px;
}
```